# PHP Fractal transformer return embedded data

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to use Fractal for transforming API data output. This works for single items and collections, but I can't seem to get it working with embedded data. Unfortunately, I can't find lots of "how to's" on Fractal. I followed the info on the Fractal site, but it won't work. I'm using Laravel 4 as my framework.

This is what I have on my Transformer class:

```
    protected $availableEmbeds = array(
    'requirements'
);
    public function transform(){ etc... }

    public function embedRequirements(Regions $regions)
{
    return $this->collection($regions->requirements, new RequirementsTransformer);
}
```

Than, inside my controller I have

```
    $regions = Regions::with($this->eagerLoad)->get();
```

This gives me the result I want.

But when I pass this data to the transformer it doesn't provide the desired result:

```
    return $this->respondWithCollection($regions, new RegionTransformer());
```

RespondWithCollection method

```
    protected function respondWithCollection($collection, $callback)
{
    $resource = new Collection($collection, $callback);

    $fractalManager = new Manager();
    $rootScope = $fractalManager->createData($resource);
    //$rootScope = $this->fractal->createData($resource);

    return $this->respondWithArray($rootScope->toArray());
}
```

This is the output:

```
    {
"data": [
    {
        "id": 36218,
        "name": "Netherlands",
        "active": true,
        "created": "2014-02-28 11:17:02"
    }
],
"embeds": [
    "requirements"
]
```

}

Where I was expecting "requirements" to be part of a relations key inside the "data" key.

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! How are you requesting the data?

Comment: $regions = Regions::with($this->eagerLoad)->get();

Comment: That just queries your database. Embeds are detected with `GET /regions?embed=requirements`.

Comment: Oh, you mean how I set the embeds? 
I request region?embed=requirements. I set `$this->fractal->setRequestedScopes(explode(',', Input::get('embed')));`.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm hitting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem just yet. The solutions was

Transformer class:

```
public function embedRequirements(Regions $regions)
{
    $requirements = $regions->requirements()->get();
    return $this->collection($requirements, new RequirementsTransformer);
}
```

The get() made all the difference

$regions->requirements()**->get()**;